# How to reconnect to ray cluster after the cluster restarted?

Tags: python, fastapi, ray

I have a question regarding the reconnection process between a ray cluster and a FastAPI server. On FastAPI I init/connect to the ray cluster in the startup event:

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
async def init_ray():
    ...
    ray.init(address=f'{ray_head_host}:{ray_head_port}', _redis_password=ray_redis_password, namespace=ray_serve_namespace)

    ...
```

In the case of a restart of the ray cluster I ran into a problem when I want to use the ray API in some FastAPI routes:

```
Exception: Ray Client is not connected. Please connect by calling `ray.connect`.
```

So it seems that the connection from FastAPI to ray is lost (this is also confirmed by `ray.is_initilized()` ==> `False`). But if I try to re-connect using `ray.init()` I got the following error:

```
Exception: ray.connect() called, but ray client is already connected
```

I also tried to call `ray.shutdown()` infornt of the re-init call without success.

Maybe someone has an idea how to reconnect from FastAPI?

Comment: Sebastian, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a daemon thread that keeps checking the ray connection. If ray client is disconnected, reconnect by calling your startup function `init_ray()`

```
import threading
from ray.util.client import ray as ray_stub

class RayConn(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            # sleep for 30 seconds
            time.sleep(30)
            if not ray_stub.is_connected():
                logger.error("Ray client is disconnected. Trying to reconnect")
                try:
                    try:
                        ray.shutdown()
                        logger.info("Shutdown complete.")
                    except BaseException as e:
                        logger.error(f"Failed to shutdown: {e}")
                    reestablish_conn() # your function that call ray.init() and task creation, if any
                    logger.info(f"Successfully reconnected, reconnect count: {reconnect_count}")
                except BaseException as ee:
                    logger.error(f"Failed to to connect to ray head! {ee}")


RayConn()
```

Answer (score 1):

I end up using a [context manager](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) to manage the connection to ray.

```py
class RayConnection:
    def __init__(self, address, **kwargs):
        ray.init(address=address, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        ray.shutdown()
```

Then you can wrap your ray calls in it and have it always properly closed and re-opened.

```py
with RayConnection():
    print(ray.available_resources())
```